# Контейнеризация для локальной разработки

Tags: docker

Всем привет, мы разрабатываем интернет-магазин. 
Работаем по классической схеме, имеем dev и production,
всю разработку ведем локально.

Проблема в следующем: проект достаточно большой, постоянно появляются новые разработчики, и каждому нужно объяснять, что надо надо ставить себе OpenServer, выбирать нужную конфигурацию, кучу настроек и т.д.

Естественно я написал инструкцию, но понимаю, что так продолжаться не может, т.к. каждый новый разработчик, тратит пару дней, на настройки окружения.

Нам нравится работать на OpenServer, т.к. файловая структура проекта доступна прямо у нас на нашем рабочем компьютере, и любая `IDE` может без проблем открыть проект.

Начал читать про docker, понимаю, что это то, что нам необходимо.

Но возникает много вопрос, на которые не могу найти ответы:

1. Правильно понимаю, что docker можно также спокойно использовать локально на windows ? Как вы локально разворачиваете докер ?
2. При разворачивании проекта через docker, создается некая виртуализация. Как тогда работать с проектом через IDE ? Если все окружение проекта на linux, а мы работаем на windows, как вообще люди работают через IDE в таких случаях ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Для запуска docker в windows лучше воспользоваться [wsl2](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/wsl/compare-versions).
2. Пробрасывают порты и шарят директории с помощью [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).

Comment: Вообще говоря, многие ide уже "понимают" докер и умеют подключаться к контейнерам (например, для отладки)